# Does Facebook Graph API would show real time updates?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to know if Facebook Graph API is able to show all real time updates of Facebook Pages as soon as posts are published?
My target is only to know the fact there is something new on prefered Facebook Page and I will check the content on my own.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/real-time-updates/v2.1

> Changes are aggregated and sent in batch at most once every 5 seconds, or when the number of unsent changes exceeds 1000 - your server callback should be able to handle this level of load.

In my tests i got new entries with the Realtime API in less than 30 seconds all the time.